# Orthogonal Set proving

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, orthogonality

The matrix set is

\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 &-1 \\  \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -2 \\ -2 &2 \\  \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 3 & -3 \\  3 & -3 \\  \end{bmatrix}

I know that a set of nonzero vectors  $\{ u_1, u_2,\cdots,u_m \}$  is called orthogonal if  $u_i \cdot u_j = 0$  whenever  $i \neq j$. It was insisted that this is an orthogonal set but when the formula is applied to the  first and last matrix it yields:
\begin{bmatrix} 6 & -6 \\  -6 & 6 \\  \end{bmatrix} which doesn't satisfy the  $u_i \cdot u_j = 0$ condition. Am I doing something wrong? or it really isn't an orthogonal set.

Moreover, can I say that this is also an orthonormal set since an orthogonal set is automatically an orthonormal set?
Thanks!

Comment: You need to first define a scalar product or orthogonal will not have a meaning.

Comment: It is supposed to be orthogonal with respect to which inner product?

Comment: for square matrices $A,B$ the usual inner product is $$ \operatorname{trace} A^T B $$  which is, also, equal to $$ \operatorname{trace} B^T A $$

Comment: Cf. [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product)

Comment: Ah yes you're exactly correct. The inner product is trace A^TB. I was treating it as a simple dot product A*B when it should be A^TB. I see it now. Thank you for all your help. :)